# JavaScript NestJS: get param in Render() method

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have 2 hbs files ie: test.template.de.hbs and test.template.en.hbs

```
  @Get('/test/:locale')
  @Render(`/templates/test.template.${@Param() locale}.hbs`)
  root(): any {
    return { test: 1 };
  }
```

I would like to render the file depending on what I give in params, but I'm not sure how I can save it and whether it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

`@Render()` is a decorator, so it doesn't have access to other decorators like `@Param()`. What you could do instead is inject `@Res()` and call `res.render()` so that you have access to the `@Param()` value